# Bootstrap form input looks out of order on iPhone but good on android

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

My website form looks good on desktop and android browsers but i have slightly out of order look on iphone. I am using bootstrap "col-xs-12" to make it take whole row on small screens but on iPhone it takes half a row is a little lower on y-axis.

```
<span class="col-xs-12">Datum prijave</span>
<input name="checkin" class="col-xs-12" type="date" value="2016-01-12" required="">

<span class="xol-xs-12">Datum odjave</span>
<input name="checkout" class="col-xs-12" type="date" value="2016-01-12" required="">
```

[image: Left is iphone, and on right how it should be]

[website link](http://www.gastroid-hotel.ba/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to your class calls

```
<span class="xol-xs-12">Datum odjave</span>
```

should be

```
<span class="col-xs-12">Datum odjave</span>
```